# How to unit test code inside subscribe using jest

Tags: angular, jestjs

Hi can anyone provide me the example how we can unit test inside subscribe function using jest. I am using angular 12 and latest jest

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
describe('provides information for one item', () => {
    function doIt() {
        // Here, code to trigger the observable

        // Call complete, thus finalize
        subscription.unsubscribe(); 
    }

    it('provides a state', (done) => {
        const states = new Set<string>();
        subscription = service.oneItemInformation$.state$
            .pipe(
                finalize(() => {
                    expect(states.has('loading')).toBe(true);
                    expect(states.has('success')).toBe(true);
                    expect(states.size).toBe(2);
                    done();
                }),
            )
            .subscribe((state: string) => {
                states.add(state);
            });
        doIt();
    });

    it('provides one item', (done) => {
        let count = 0;
        subscription = service.oneItemInformation$.pipe(finalize(() => done())).subscribe((item: Item) => {
            switch (++count) {
                case 1:
                    expect(item).toBeUndefined();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    expect(item).toBe(item1);
                    break;
                default:
                    fail();
            }
        });
        doIt();
    });

    it('gives no size', (done) => {
        subscription = service.totalSize$.pipe(finalize(() => done())).subscribe((_state: StateValue<number>) => {
            fail();
        });
        doIt();
    });
});
```

The trick is to use `done()` to ensure the subscription is made, to call it in `finalize()`, and for this, to complete the observable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [fakeAsync](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync) and [tick()](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/tick) like in the following example:

In your component:

```
export class YourComponent {
  public foo() {
    this.subscriptions.add(this.someService.bar().subscribe((next) => {
      if(next) {
        this.foobar();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

In your .spec file:

```
describe('testing', () => {
  it('should call foobar', fakeAsync(() => {
    const foobarSpy = jest.spyOn(component, 'foobar');
    jest.spyOn(TestBed.inject(SomeService), 'bar').mockReturnValue(of(true));
    
    component.foo();

    tick(1);

    expect(foobarSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));

  it('should not call foobar', fakeAsync(() => {
    const foobarSpy = jest.spyOn(component, 'foobar');
    jest.spyOn(TestBed.inject(SomeService), 'bar').mockReturnValue(of(false));
    
    component.foo();

    tick(1);

    expect(foobarSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
});
```